# Python global variable/dynamic interpreted?

Tags: python

I have this code which works as expected:

```
foo = 123

def fooBar():
    print(foo)   ### cannot find foo from local scope, checks prev and prints 123
    #foo = 987
    #print(foo)

fooBar()
```

But when I change the code to the following,

```
foo = 123

def fooBar():
    print(foo)   ### blows up here... 
    foo = 987
    print(foo)
    
fooBar()
```

it blows up on the print statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in fooBar
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

I know I can get around the problem using `global foo` inside my function, but the error I was expected was *not on line number I was expecting.* I was assuming it would still print `123` and then blow up when I try to assign another value to `foo`.

It seems as if Python parses `fooBar()` and knows I do an assignment of `foo` later in local function and then blows up on the `print`, instead of grabbing the global value? Is that right?

Comment: the linked duplicate is really close, and the accepted answer explains exactly this interesting point. The byte-compiler sees the use of `foo` as local, thus it uses this local reference in the whole function. So it's not as dynamic as we thought (I learned that myself very recently)

Comment: Local variables are defined at function level, and their names exist since the beginning of the function. `print foo` in the second snippet refers always to the local `foo` which, at the point of the first line, has not been assigned any value yet.

Comment: FWIW : "Almost like Python interpreter parses fooBar() and knows I do an assignment of foo later in local function" is __exactly__ what happens. Python is dynamic indeed but it's still compiled to bytecode (just like Java), not naiveley interpreted line-by-line like you might believe.

Comment: Your theory is correct. The first version works because Python can't find `foo` in `fooBar`'s locals, so it looks in the globals. But in the 2nd version it knows that `foo` must be local to  `fooBar` because it makes an assignment to it, and there's no `global` directive.

Comment: I'm on board but one other question:
in the above example foo's a primitive type, and if I change to a list and change foo=987 to foo.append(987) it works. So when the byte-compiler compiles does it check global or does it just check primitive assignemtns?

Works:
foo = [1]

def fooBar():
  print foo 
  
  foo.append(2)
  print foo    

fooBar()

Comment: @KevinSoltis the compiler checks for *any assignment* and marks the *variable* as local. Note, **there are no primitive types in Python**